# React JS inLayer enail-editor How lot Load Design sotored in db

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am using the unLayer email-editor in my React JS app.  I can save the design in a json formatted string bit am unable to load it back again.
I am storing the formatted json in a SQL Server db as a NVARCHAR(MAX) data type.
i.e..

```
 {"counters":{"u_column":1,"u_row":1,"u_content_heading":1},"body":{"id":"kYAVewVGZV","rows":[{"id":"-ftc8jq.....etc
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with my React JS app code or how I retrieve the Json in my c# MVC.

The error I am getting is...***'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')'***

And looking deeper into the browser devtools Source tab I aslo see this error..

```
ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called")
```

This is the code for React email-editor for the loadDesign....

```
NewsletterService.RetrieveNewsletterDesignById(selectedDesignId)
            .then((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    if (data !== 'FAIL') {
                        if (this.mounted) {                            
                            console.log("load data = " + data)
                            this.editor.loadDesign(data)
                        }
                        return
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

Note, in the console.log line it displays the json string exactly as it is in the db but when i go the 'Network' tab in the browser devtools and highlight the above service it has placed escape back slashes throughout the json string (screemshot below)  Is this what it is reading and causing the problem?...

[image: Netork tab in devtools]

Here is the C# MVC code for the above service that retrieves the json

**Implementation:**

```
         public async Task< string []> RetrieveNewsletterDesignById (int designId)
        {
            var context = new HubbleDBContext ();
           
               var resultTask = new Task<string []>(() =>
                {
                    var result = context.eNewsLetterDesigns
                        .Where(soughtNewsLetterDesign => (soughtNewsLetterDesign.DesignId == designId))
                        .Select(soughtNewsLetterDesign => soughtNewsLetterDesign.DesignStructure)
                     .ToArray ();

                return result;               
                 });

            resultTask.Start ();

            return await resultTask;
            }          
          }
```

**And the Controller for the above service:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RetrieveNewsletterDesignById(int designId)
        // Returns the Json design only
        {
            try
            {
                  return Json(await newslettersService.RetrieveNewsletterDesignById(designId), "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    //return Content(await newslettersService.RetrieveNewsletterDesignById(designId), "application/json");             
                  //  return Json (await eventsService.RetrieveEventById (eventId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await newslettersService.RetrieveNewsletterDesignById(designId));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return LoggedError(exception);
            }
        }
```

As you can see from the above Controller I have tried different permuations of retrieving the (already) Json string and my hunch is this is where the issue may lie?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've resolved the issue.

It was in my C# implementation, I was returning a string array rather than just a simple string.  Corrected code:

```
 var resultTask = new Task<string>(() =>
            {
                string result = context.eNewsLetterDesigns
                    .Where(soughtNewsLetterDesign => (soughtNewsLetterDesign.DesignId == designId))
                    .Select(soughtNewsLetterDesign => soughtNewsLetterDesign.DesignStructure)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

                return result;
```

and in my controller...

```
return Content(await newslettersService.RetrieveNewsletterDesignById(designId), "application/json");
```